# Back up Oracle with script (Insert statements, DDL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to backup part of a database with Insert and DDL statements with output similar to what you can get with TOAD or SQL Developer, but from a script.

Details:
This is to be able to see changes and differences with source control.
We are using SQL Developer, LINUX tools and Python (With Oracle).

Comment: I hesitated flagging it as too broad, but finally it was not too long to answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this? Change settings as per your need.

Exporting Schema:

1) Run following in command prompt (not mandatory though)

```
SET NLS_LANG AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF.8
```

2) Once above is set run the below, run the below. Change username/password/schemaname, path to export

```
exp userid=<schemaname>/<pwd>@<dbname or SID> file=<localpath\1.dmp> 
    log=<localpath\2.log>  buffer=1000000000 feedback=25000 
    direct=y recordlength=64000 owner=<schemaname>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be tools for what you are trying to do (other than TOAD and PL/SQL).

This is a great project you have if you intend to write the code for this. You must work as follows:

### For DDLs

. Write a script that list all the objects you need to extract; this will be tables, schemas, procedures, functions:

```
for x in (
    select * from dba_objects where object_type in ('PACKAGES', 'TABLES', '>others>') loop
     --- things to do with x.>columns<
end loop;

for u in (
    select * from dba_users where username in ( <list of needed schemas> ) loop
)
     --- things to do with users
end loop;
```

. Then from above list, you have  Oracle function `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` that generates the DDL. e.g. with users:

```
begin
for u in (select * from dba_users where <list of needed schemas> 
              order by username)
    loop
      dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', u.username); 
    end loop;
end;
```

### For the inserts

(this could take time to generate on databases with large tables (thousands of rows is already a lot for my approach).

I advise you create a generic function that generates the insert statements. This is rather simple as long as it does not include `BLOB` and `CLOB`. You take each column of each table.

Remember to generate the inserts in an orderly way, otherwise the comparison will not be possible.

The generic function should take a table as input. From the table name, it gets the columns from `dba_tables`, then selects the table.

```
--- plsql code below lists the columns of the tables
begin
    for t in (select * from dba_tables order by table_name) loop
        for c in (select * from dba_tab_columns where table_name=t.table_name and owner=t.owner order by owner, table_name, column_name) loop
            dbms_output.put_line(c.table_name||'.'||c.column_name);
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
```

Here is how you could collect the values in an array, then loop on this array to display the insert statements as text (with dbms_output.put_line)

```
declare
    type t_v is table of varchar2(32000);
    t_vchars t_v;
    v_ins varchar2(2000):=' ';
    v_sel varchar2(2000):=' ';
    v_res varchar2(4030):=' ';        
begin
    for t in (select * from dba_tables order by table_name) loop
        v_ins :='insert into '||t.table_name||'(';
        v_sel :=' select ';
        for c in (select * from dba_tab_columns where table_name=t.table_name and owner=t.owner) loop
            v_ins:= v_ins||c.column_name||',';
            v_sel:= v_sel||'''''''||'||c.column_name||'||'''''',';
        end loop;
        -- remove last comma
        v_ins:= substr(v_ins,1,length(v_ins)-1);
        v_sel:= substr(v_sel,1,length(v_sel)-1);
        v_ins:= v_ins||')';
        v_sel:= v_sel||' from dual';
        v_res:= 'select '''||v_ins||v_sel||''' from '||t.table_name;
        -- above, you still need to insert an order by, but I let you choose which solution 
        execute immediate v_res bulk collect into t_vchars;
        FOR i in 1..t_vchars.count LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(t_vchars(i)||';');
        END LOOP;
    end loop;
end;
```

### After you're done and want to test the whole script.

One tricky thing when you want to test and run the inserts is if you have foreign key. You must deactivate them before inserting, otherwise you need to do the inserts in a ordered way, which is not easy to do.

```
for c in (select * from dba_constraints)
loop
   --- disable constraint
end loop;
```

Then after inserts are done

```
for c in (select * from dba_constraints)
loop
   --- enable constraint
end loop;
```